# UI placement in Android

Tags: android, cordova, user-interface, native-code

I have been developing applications using PhoneGap however the app looks different on each device i.e buttons are in different places. DIVs are bigger than they're meant to be. So I was wondering which route do I have to take to make the UI look the same on all devices. Do I have to do native coding? Or maybe use something like Titanium and ditch PhoneGap. I couldn't find any answer anywhere else which Is why I came here.

**EDIT #1:**

My biggest flaw is design, so which is the best option for me? One which requires less design and more logic based coding?

Comment: have you tried google chrome emulation?

Comment: @IllegalArgument is there a framework which can be used alongside PhoneGap one which you would suggest out of personal experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PhoneGap however the app looks different on each device
```

This is were the power of Mobile UI frameworks come into play. The Mobile UI frameworks ( Dojo Toolkit, Sencha Touch, Ionic, Kendo UI and many more) help you to develop apps that **mimic/impersonate** the Mobile device.
These frameworks will have themes ( `Android theme, Iphone theme, Blackberry theme, Windows theme..`) prebuilt into their framework. This themes allow you to style your application with the native look and feel. You need to just apply the themes ( importing the relevant `css` file in most cases) and you get the desired theme.
Have look over here for themes available in Dojo toolkit over [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile.html) and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/). similarly there are themes available in other Mobile UI frameworks.

```
DIVs are bigger than they're meant to be. So I was wondering which route do I have to take to make the UI look the same on all devices.
```

The most importing thing that Mobile UI frameworks help apart from look and feel is dealing with **Browser inconsistencies**. There are number of browsers ( Chrome mobile, Safari, IE, Opera and many more) which have their own way of doing things. 
The mobile UI frameworks help you in dealing with these **inconsistencies**, without you **reinventing the wheel**. They will provide **APIs** that internally deal with these inconsistencies and you do not have to bother about it.

Hope I am making sense over here.

Comment: so if I wanted the app to look same over a multitude of resolutions or is PhoneGap not the way to go for that?

Comment: PhoneGap/Cordova allows you to use all the above mentioned UI frameworks. The above frameworks are all HTML5/CSS3 compliant. What phonegap/cordova offers is the ability to use HTML5/CSS3 to create **CROSS PLATFORM** apps, which in additional to being cross/platform ( **IF** you have used HTLM5/CSS3) allows you to access **NATIVE DEVICE** api's. If you **DO NOT WANT** to use the native look and feel themes provided by the UI framework, You than need to write your **OWN** theme using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This may not the answer your looking for but just try F12 and click tab Emulation theres a lot of phone ui available to check your design.

[image]

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of responsive framework for UI. Like `Jquery mobile` OR `Ionic` etc. Responsive frameworks help the UI to look almost same in all devices. If you don't break the responsiveness while modifying frameworks should serve your purpose well.